# High Availability on Glassfish

Tags: java, web-applications, glassfish, high-availability

I've been facing the following problem since the first time I used glassfish:

Every time I need to upgrade one of my applications I just redeploy the new version on glassfish, everything works fine, except for the fact that my application stops for a few seconds during redeployment, and only becomes available again after the process is complete. I know that is completely normal and it's how it's supposed to be, but my application really needs to be available all the time, I already tried using glassfish clusters but the same thing happened.

Does anyone knows how keep the application running during redeployment?

Comment: Have you considered just having a second application on another server and re-rerouting traffic to that one. After upgrading the application - you can then route back to the original?

Comment: There is a way to invoke sticky sessions that should maintain session affinity: https://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/glassfish-4-cluster-sticky-sessions